# smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server - trying to send email via Django

Tags: python, django, docker, email

I have a Docker container where I am trying to send an email via Django.

**I have a separate email server on another domain that I want to use for this purpose. I have other applications connect with it with no problem.**

My Django production email setup looks like this (I intend to replace username and password with Kubernetes secrets in the future, but for testing I am just putting them inside the file):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.mydomain.io'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "<username>"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "<password>"
```

In my module, I have the following code:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class MailView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):

        subject = request.data.get("subject")
        message = request.data.get("message")
        sender = request.data.get("sender")
        receipients = request.data.get("receipients")

        send_mail(subject,message,sender,receipients,fail_silently=False,)
        ... more
```

This works locally, however when I try to run it inside the container, I get the following error:

```
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Do I need to install some sort of SMTP relay or server to my Docker container?

My Docker container is based on the `python:3.7` container and I am not currently installing any SMTP extensions or anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

`EMAIL_USE_TLS` needs to be set to `True`

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```